About the influence theorem in Geoffrey Grimmett's book
Let $N \geq 1$ and $E=\{1,2, \ldots, N\}$, and write $\Omega=\{0,1\}^E$. Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\Omega$ and $A$ an event (that is, a subset of $\Omega$ ).The absolute influence is
$$
I_A(e)=\mu\left(1_A\left(\omega^e\right) \neq 1_A\left(\omega_e\right)\right),
$$
The theorem is:
4.28 Theorem (Influence) There exists a constant $c \in(0, \infty)$ such that the following holds. Let $N \geq 1$, let $E$ be a finite set with $|E|=N$, and let $A$ be a subset of $\Omega=\{0,1\}^E$ with $\phi(A) \in(0,1)$. Then
$$
\sum_{e \in E} I_A(e) \geq c \phi(A)(1-\phi(A)) \log \left[1 / \max _e I_A(e)\right],
$$
where the reference measure is $\phi=\phi_{\frac{1}{2}}$. There exists $e \in E$ such that
$$
I_A(e) \geq c \phi(A)(1-\phi(A)) \frac{\log N}{N} \text {. }
$$
Here, $\phi$ is the product measure with density $p$ on $\Omega_p$, I am now have no idea how to conclude the very second inequality from the first, in the book, he said:
We may assume that $m=\max _e I_A(e)$ satisfies $m>0$, since otherwise
$$
\phi(A)(1-\phi(A))=0 .
$$
Since
$$
\sum_{e \in E} I_A(e) \leq N m
$$
we have by (4.29) that
$$
\frac{m}{\log (1 / m)} \geq \frac{c \phi(A)(1-\phi(A))}{N} .
$$
Inequality (4.30) follows with an amended value of $c$, by the monotonicity of $m / \log (1 / m)$ or otherwise.
But I don't know hot to get this $\log N$, the theorem is here on page 68.
For $\omega \in \Omega$ and $e \in E$, we define the configurations $\omega^e, \omega_e$ by $\quad \omega^e(f)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\omega(f) & \text { if } f \neq e, \\ 1 & \text { if } f=e,\end{array} \quad \omega_e(f)= \begin{cases}\omega(f) & \text { if } f \neq e, \\ 0 & \text { if } f=e .\end{cases}\right.$

What is $\omega^e, \omega_e$?

I added the definition in the problem
